# Name change in reservation ticket

Tags: air-travel, tickets

Me and my husband want to go Darjeeling. When we done our reservation there is a problem: in the ticket I reserved to my husband's name and my Aunty's name. Can I change the Aunty name to my name?

Comment: Depends on the airline and the fare class you booked.  Best source of information is to call the airline direct or travel agency that made your booking.

Comment: Why is this tagged "Japan"?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the airline and the ticket bought, typically costs money. All this can be found on the airline website.

Comment: Yes. And some airlines actually allow to cancel the ticket free of charge within 24 hours of booking. This may be an option as well (to cancel and rebook again a few minutes later).

Comment: If the OP is talking about Darjeeling, India, there is no airport nearby and they are likely referring to a train reservation.

Comment: @DCTLib well, in the USA it's a requirement https://www.transportation.gov/sites/dot.gov/files/docs/Notice_24hour_hold_final20130530.pdf and outside of the USA I don't think I heard of this practice. Norwegian is generous with https://www.norwegian.com/uk/customer-services/travel-information/tickets-/ 4 hours.

Comment: @jpatokal But the Tag says "Japan". So the OP may be going from Japan to Darjeeling - in that case, the post *may* talk about flights.